# iCloud Keychain keeps losing data

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

I'm using `kSecAttrSynchronizable` for synchronizing keychain data across devices via the iCloud Keychain (using [Valet](https://github.com/square/Valet)) and for the most part it works fine.

Once or twice a day though, the keychain loses its data and takes several seconds after app startup to re-fetch it. Has anyone noticed this behavior? If so, any known workarounds other than to do a re-check after several seconds in the hope that the data is back.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I had the accessibility on unlock instead of first unlock.